# Compiling TypeScript project inside ASP.NET5 project

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core

I installed the latest ASP.NET5 beta8 and create new project. Inside project I created a new folder, added tsproject.json file and wrote some TypeScript files .ts

I want to compile my TypeScript sub-project automatically. What should I do? Should I write some kind of grunt task, enable automatic TypeScript file compilation in VS (but will it compile all files in folder using tsconfig.json settings??), or something else?

Comment: You have many possibilities. I do not personally use visual studios but I have worked with grunt. On a personal basis I prefer gulp for this. I run a **gulp watch** and on save it'll transpile my ts to js. I have it set up so it'll keep the same folder structure (rather than compile everything to one js file). If you want some advice on visual studio + typescript + angular (or not) I highly recommend watching this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fw3ihDINdbk and checking the channel. Cheers.

Comment: That's incredible video! Thank you for sharing it!

Comment: yeah it answered a lot of my questions. This one was also very nice. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OZxnFB0yQHs . If you find the answer to your question, remember to add the answer to this post. I believe there are a lot of people that need clarity on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a [tsconfig.json](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/tsconfig.json) file to the root of your project:

```
{
  // TypeScript to JavaScript compilation options. Add what you want here.
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": true,   // Do not allow implicit any variables.
    "noEmitOnError": true,   // Stop processing on error.
    "removeComments": false, // Do not remove comments.
    "sourceMap": false,      // Do not create source map files.
    "module": "commonjs",    // Use the Common JS modules or some other format.
    "target": "es5"          // Compile to ECMAScript 5.
  },
  // Exclude the bower_components, node_modules and wwwroot folders from
  // being scanned for TypeScript (.ts) or TypeScript definition (.d.ts) files.
  "exclude": [
    "bower_components",
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

Add the `gulp-typescript` to compile .ts files, `gulp-concat` to concatenate files and `merge-stream` to merge Gulp streams to `package.json`:

```
{
    // Omitted...
    "devDependencies": {
        // Omitted...
        "gulp-concat": "2.6.0",
        "gulp-typescript": "2.9.2",
        "merge-stream": "1.0.0"
    }
}
```

In your gulpfile.js file, add a new build TypeScript task (I show how to do incremental building for faster build times so this is a little advanced, you can look at the documentation for gulp-typescript if you want to look at something simpler):

```
var gulp = require("gulp");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var typescript = require("gulp-typescript");
var merge = require("merge-stream");

// A TypeScript project is used to enable faster incremental compilation, 
// rather than recompiling everything from scratch each time. Each 
// resulting compiled file has it's own project which is stored in 
// the typeScriptProjects array.
var typeScriptProjects = [];
function getTypeScriptProject(name) {
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < typeScriptProjects.length; ++i) {
        if (typeScriptProjects[i].name === name) {
            item = typeScriptProjects[i];
        }
    }

    if (item === undefined) {
        // Use the tsconfig.json file to specify how TypeScript (.ts) 
        // files should be compiled to JavaScript (.js).
        var project = typescript.createProject("tsconfig.json");
        item = { name: name, project: project };
        typeScriptProjects.push(item);
    }

    return item.project;
}

var sources = {
    // An array containing objects required to build a single JavaScript file.
    ts: [
        {
            // name - The name of the final JavaScript file to build.
            name: "main.js",
            // paths - A single or array of paths to TypeScript files.
            paths: [
                "Folder1/one.ts",
                "Folder1/two.ts",
                "Folder2/**/*.ts"
            ]
        }
    ]
};

gulp.task("build-ts", function () {
    var tasks = sources.ts.map(function (source) { // For each set of source files in the sources.
        return gulp                                // Return the stream.
            .src(source.paths)                     // Start with the source paths.
            .pipe(typescript(getTypeScriptProject(source))) // Compile TypeScript (.ts) to JavaScript (.js) using the specified options.
            .pipe(concat(source.name))             // Concatenate JavaScript files into a single file with the specified name.
            .pipe(gulp.dest("./wwwroot/js/"));     // Saves the JavaScript file to the specified destination path.
    });
    return merge(tasks);                           // Combine multiple streams to one and return it so the task can be chained.
});
```

Comment: Thank your for your answer. And for excellent ASP.NET 5 Boilerplate project as well! BTW Can I use several tsconfig.json and put them inside subfolders?

Comment: Cool, you've used it! I think the above code is already in boilerplate or will be in the next version so you can see it in action there. I believe you can but I've not tried. What's your scenario which requires you to have more than one?

Comment: I want to compile different large modules of my project into separate js files and download them on-demand using smth like AMD. I think it's better to describe my intention in each tsconfig.json then hide it in code inside gulpfile.js

Comment: In my code above, where you are creating a new project, you can point to a second tsconfig.json file. It's all JavaScript so you can add as many as you want. I myself am looking into Common JS using Browserify rather than AMD with RequireJS which requires another loader script. Will add it to Boilerplate at some point.

Answer (score 0):

> > BTW Can I use several tsconfig.json and put them inside subfolders?

tsc -p ./subfolder